# Expo Push Notification not working on standalone app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, push

I made the setup for push notifications using the expo push system and it works fine when using the app through ExpoGo. But in the installed app from the play store, it doesnt work. Debugging the app I found out that the

```
token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
```

is returning nothing because the alert after it never runs.

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    alert('1')
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    alert('2')
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
        name: 'default',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
      });
    }

    //sending the token to my api
    api.put('xxx', {
      notification_token: token,
    });
  }
```

What should I do? Is anything I am missing? I just used the codes given in the docs https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

The point is that in the docs of setup the push notifications, for some reason they dont mention there that is necessary to setup a firebase account to push notifications work in the standalone app even if I'm using the expo system.

Discovered the solution in this link https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9770

And setted up the FCM with this link https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Antony Leme, I followed the docs and finished the configuration, but could you please tell me from where are you sending the notifications?

Comment: Dont know if I got your question but I have a backend in Laravel where I send a request to the expo server to send the notification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Which dependency are you using with Laravel?

Comment: This is how I'm doing it https://pastebin.com/KDcun4hg

Comment: Thank you @Antony Leme! So push notifications for standalone IOS & Android can be achieved without using FCM

Comment: Not actually. What I realized is that it works like a charm for iOs without FCM, but  for Android you still need to setup the FCM.

Comment: Ahh nice, and could you please tell me what did you use in Laravel? Did you use Pusher?

Answer (score 1):

The [expo push notification documentation page](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/) is not super clear in mentioning that, there are few steps needed for push notification to work in a standalone android/ios app. Although it mentions in the documentation as "Next Steps" at the bottom of the page, but from the first paragraph it is not certainly clear that they are distinguishing expo app notification from standalone android/ios app notification. Rather it felt that Expo takes care of all the things as if no more steps require for standalone apps. It is certainly right only for Expo app. However, when we land into the [Next Steps](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/) page, we find the most important information in the "Credentials" section.

So this is how it works for Android Stand alone app (which I have done). We need to setup our own Firebase project as it says here [Using FCM for Push Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/). If you are using Expo server to send Push notification, make sure to follow the steps "Upload Server Credentials". You will see the FCM Server Key added in your Expo Credentials.

It should not take too much of a time but for me it took 1 hour or so to setup these extra steps as I was learning these, for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on android. Following were the steps which helped me resolve the issue.

1. create firebase project and add sha key (not sure if it's necessary)
2. enable cloud messaging API on firebase and upload the server key to expo servers as fcm key `expo push:android:upload --api-key <server-key>`
3. add the 96x96px notification icon in directory and add the path in the

> app.json file
> "notification": {
> "icon": "./src/assets/notificationIcon.png",
> "color": "#ffffff",
> "iosDisplayInForeground": true
> }

4. create android file with `expo prebuild --platform android`
5. add `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')` in `android/app/build.gradle` file.
6. add following permissions in manifest file.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
> ```

7. rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, due to misleading documentation. There is not need to set channel.

```
await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync() // removed this line
```

It started working, If we set channel then channel id must be send in request object.

Answer (score -1):

Notifications on android haven't worked on our project. And in addition to other answers some of the following helped:

- I've uploaded FCM service key to Expo
- Put SHA certificate fingerprint to Firebase project
- Set `experienceId` explicitly in `getExpoPushTokenAsync`